# What is the problem with the following piece of code?

Tags: c

This piece of code seems to be creating some troubles while compiling. Any explanation?

```
int i =20;
int maxlen = i;
int main()
{
     int j = i;
     printf("i=%d , j=%d\n", i , j);
}
```

Answer (score 5):

In C, you can't initialize global variables using non-constant expressions. Initializing maxlen to i fails because `i` is not a constant expression. It's part of the C standard.

Why not `#define` a constant?

```
#define MAXLEN 20
```

Comment: I think With the C99 standard you can use const keyword instead of define.

Comment: @Ubiquite, @Rafe, no in C99 you still can't. A "`const` qualified variable" is not a constant in the sense of th C99 standard. You could only use an `enum` constant to work around this.

Answer (score 5):

You can only use compile-time constants when initializing a variable at that scope. Try:

```
int i = 20;
int maxlen;

int main()
{
   maxlen = i; // assign within the scope of a function
   int j = i;
   printf("i=%d , j=%d\n", i , j);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This Code is Invalid in **C** but valid in **C++**:

C - http://www.ideone.com/mxgMo

Error Reason **-: initializer element is not constant**

C++ - http://www.ideone.com/XzoeU

**Works**.

Because:

The **C++** Standard states:

**3.6.1 Main function [basic.start.main]**

1 A program shall contain a global function called main, which is the designated start of the program. It is implementation defined whether a program in a freestanding environment is required to define a main function. [ Note: in a freestanding environment, start-up and termination is implementation-defined; **start-up contains the execution of constructors for objects of namespace scope with static storage duration; termination contains the execution of destructors for objects with static storage duration**. —end note ]

However, **C99** says this:

**56.7.8 Initialization**

**4 All the expressions in an initializer for an object that has static storage duration 
shall be constant expressions or string literals.**

So not just the code you posted, but something like this will also be invalid in **C**:

```
#include<stdio.h>

int needint(void);

int i =needint();

int needint(void)
{
    return 1;
}

int main()
{
   int j = i;
   printf("i=%d , j=%d\n", i , j);
}
```

[See here](http://www.ideone.com/efBGQ).